# Can I add the last custom row myself? : CsvMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv, export-to-csv

I want to add the last row Custom added before writing to csv file

This is example picture, I need to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNvC.png)

this is my code

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String filepath = properties.getExportPath();
        String fileName = utilityService.getYesterdayDate() + TendermintETLConstants.POSTFIX_NDID_RP_IDP_SUMMARY_CSV;
        String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(blockList);
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(BlockForSummaryCSV.class).withHeader();
        csvMapper.addMixIn(Block.class, BlockForSummaryCSV.class);
        Block[] blockArray = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonInString, Block[].class);
        csvMapper.writerFor(Block[].class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .writeValue(new File(filepath + TendermintETLConstants.SEPARATE_DIRECTORY_SYMBOL + fileName), blockArray);
    }
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yes you can, just modify the contents of `jsonInString` or the `blockList` before writing it to file. Note that there are far easier ways to process/save CSV files that may suit your needs better, namely by simply writing a line at a time like a text file and appending your data to the last line or adding a new line to the end.

Comment: i try add a value of list put to another list object , but i don't know it has a specific structure I figured out how to put it together.

Comment: @sorifiend thank you very mush,

 I use modify the contents of `jsonInString`, (subString and +String)

 Which I tried modify `blockList ` It can't do it

Comment: You can only modify the json string if the data remains valid, Maybe use a json library so that you can edit the data correctly.